# Why does this code print two times?

Tags: c, fork, newline, printf, stdio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Working of fork() in linux gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
  printf ("ciao");
  fork ();
}
```

I have some ideas about C optimization but I'm not sure. Hope you know the answer.

Comment: Im not quite sure that I understand the question. It's quite obvious what it prints. Also, main should return an int, and what the function fork() does isn't clear :)

Comment: Yes it prints "ciaociao". My question is about why it does print this.

Comment: I think I'll modify the title of the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find it :(

Comment: The code invokes UB -- **1**: `void main()`; **2**: no prototype for `fork()`;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code will probably print `"ciao"` twice as standard output is buffered IO so the internal buffer for standard output will be replicated in the child process and both buffers flushed when each process, the parent and child, exits.

It is unrelated to optimization.

Answer (score 4):

when fork() is called, both parent and child process inherit it and therefore they both will

print out "ciao" when they flush the buffer. If you call fflush(stdout);

before calling fork it will print only once