# buffering mechanism when fork is used in c

Tags: c, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Working of fork() in linux gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc)
>   [Why does this code print two times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581787/why-does-this-code-print-two-times)

I want to know the reason behind the output of the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int n;
   printf("%d",45);
   //fflush(stdout);
   if((n=fork())>0){
      printf("in parent\n");  
      exit(0);
   }
   else if(n==0)
       printf("%d",45);
}
```

**Output** is

```
45inparent
4545
```

If I use fflush, then **output** is

```
45inparent
45
```

Also, I am running on the linux platform

Comment: A similar post which explains more about the fork call:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2013/07/fork-system-call-and-duplicating-buffer.html

Answer (score 5):

The child process inherits the open file descriptors (stdout in this case) and the buffer associated with it.

- If you don't flush the buffer before the fork, then the content of the buffer is duplicated (including "45"), and "45" is printed twice.
- If you flush before the fork, the buffer is emptied and the child gets an empty copy of the buffer, therefore "45" is printed only once by the parent.

Answer (score 3):

The first printf() writes the string `45` in a memory buffer.

During the fork() call, the buffer is virtually duplicated in the child process, so both the parent and the child have `45` in stdout`s buffer.

Flushing that buffer in both processes will write `45` twice.