# Running fork and printing hello

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Working of fork() in linux gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc)
>   [Why does this code print two times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581787/why-does-this-code-print-two-times)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

 printf("hello\n");
 fork();

}
```

The above code prints "hello" one time.The code below prints "hello" two times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

 printf("hello");
 fork();

}
```

The code above prints "hello" two times.

Please Somebody explain this strange behavior.

Comment: this has been asked multiple times before. Please use the search function..

Comment: What happens if you use "\nhello\n" ?

Comment: The output buffer is copied to the child, and without newlines, it's not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not guaranteed to behave in this way, but the usual behaviour is: With

```
printf("hello");
```

the `"hello"` is printed to the output buffer, but that buffer is not yet flushed. Then upon the

```
fork();
```

the program state is copied to the child process, including the non-empty output buffer. Upon exit, the output buffers of parent and child are both flushed.

With the newline, the output buffer is flushed before the `fork()`.