# the unexpected output of fork() when redirected to file.txt

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, fork, process-control

I am working on process control in linux operating system using c.
the fork() function really confuse me .
what I know : when `fork()` is called
              1) whatever the code just after `fork()` , is copied to the child process.
              2) we can not determine which (parent or child) will run first.
I run the following code.

```
int main() {
    printf("Hi");
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

my first question is: why I get Hi two times?
                       it is explained in [Working of fork() in linux gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc) , but still I want someone to explain with more simplicity.

my second doubt:
                   when I redirect my output to somefile.txt
even if I use newline character (\n) the output is:

> hi
>
> hi

please explain ...

please provide me some detail if I missed , in understanding the `fork()`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:- OP has already mentioned that he has read the explanation of the question "Working of fork() in linux gcc". But it is like he is not able to get that clearly!!!! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: I realise that, but asking the exact same question again is not appropriate.  Instead, he/she should specify what, specifically, they did not understand about the previous question/answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:- Agreed Sir!!!!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : sir,If I ask in the same question within comment,then even you tell me that , if you have a question then better to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

> why I get Hi two times ?

If you write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hi");

  for (;;)
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

`"Hi"` won't be printed on `stdout`, since the standard ouput stream is line-buffered by default. This means that you have to add a `'\n'` to flush this buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hi\n");

  for (;;)
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

With `fork`, the father process' buffers will be copied into the child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hi");

  /* stdout in the father process contains "Hi" */
  fork();

  /* stdout in the father process contains "Hi" */
  /* stdout in the child process contains "Hi" */

  /* With return statement all buffers are flushed and "Hi" is printed twice */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: sir, I understand the entire concept of i/o buffer with your one code only , please suggest me some book or link ,that I should refer.

Answer (score 0):

There are there kind of buffers:

Full buffer

Line buffer

No buffer

When you use `printf` in terminal .It is `line buffer` default . So you can use `\n` to flush the buffer. After flush the buffer, you print only one `hi`

When you use `printf` redirect to a file .It is `full buffer` default . So you can  not use `\n` to flush the buffer. Without  flush the buffer, you print two `hi`

You can use [setvbuf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/setvbuf.html)`to change the buffer type.